# What does fflush(stdin) do in C programing?

Tags: c, operating-system, signals

I am very new to C programming and I am trying to understand how `fflush(stdin)` really works.

In the following example does `fflush(stdin)` clears all the buffer or it clears whatever entered after the third item? What I mean is user enters account number, space, name, space, balance. Is that true that from this point on, whatever the user enters will be flushed with `fflush(stdin)`?  and `stdin` won't be empty.

Why do I say that is because it enters into a while loop and starts writing to the text file.

My second question is whether `Ctrl-Z` will tell the OS to stop asking the user for entering input?

```
printf( "Enter the account name and balance. (separated by spaces)\n" );
  printf( "Enter EOF to end input. (Ctrl-Z)\n" );
  printf( "? " );
  scanf( "%d%s%lf", &account, name, &balance );
  fflush(stdin);

  // write account, name and balance into file with fprintf
  while ( !feof( stdin ) )
  { 
     //fflush(stdin);
     fprintf( cfPtr, "%d %s %.2f\n", account, name, balance );
     printf( "? " );
     scanf( "%d%s%lf", &account, name, &balance );
  }

  fclose( cfPtr );
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.  Don't do it, don't copy it from those that do.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Comment: @chrk Disagree with adding the 'linux` tag.  Nothing in OP's post is Linux specific.

Comment: @chrk  Yes revert.  Tags are for the Post's subject, not for the type of people seeking.

Answer (score 44):

The answer to this is that `fflush(stream)` is only formally defined for output streams, so `fflush(stdout)` is OK, but `fflush(stdin)` is not.

The purpose of `fflush(stream)` is to make the operating system flush any buffers to the underlying file. For an example of a legitimate use, students often have problems like “my prompt doesn't appear!” if they do something like:

```
printf("Enter a number: ");
```

However, they find that this works just fine:

```
printf("Enter a number:\n");
```

Of course, they don't want a newline after their prompt, so they have a bit of a problem.

The reason for this is that the output to `stdout` is buffered by the OS and the default behavior is (often) only to actually write the output to the terminal when a newline is encountered. Adding an `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf()` solves the problem:

```
printf("Enter a number: ");
fflush(stdout);
```

Now, working by analogy, people often think that `fflush(stdin)` should discard any unused input, but if you think about it a little bit that doesn't make much sense. What does it mean to “flush” an input buffer? Where is it “flushed” *to*? If you flush an output buffer, the output is sent to the underlying file or the terminal, where it would eventually wind up anyway, but where would *input* “eventually end up anyway”? There's no way of knowing! What should the behavior be if the input stream data comes from a file or a pipe or a socket? It isn't *at all* clear for input streams what the behavior of `fflush()` should be, but it's very clear for output streams in all cases. Hence, `fflush()` is only defined for output streams.

The reason why the erroneous use of `fflush(stdin)` became commonplace is that, many years ago, a few operating systems *did* implement a scheme where it worked as many people expected, discarding unused input. *Microsoft DOS* is a good example. Surprisingly, modern versions of *Linux* also implement `fflush()` for input streams.

The right thing to do with “extra” unwanted terminal input is simply to read it and do nothing with it. This is almost as easy as calling `fflush(stdin)`, works everywhere, and doesn't rely on formally undefined behavior.

The *C* standard says:

> If **stream points to an output stream** or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

[POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/fflush.html) (also explicitly defers to *C* standard):

> If **stream points to an output stream** or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, fflush() shall cause any unwritten data for that stream to be written to the file, ...

But the [Linux manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) says:

> For output streams, fflush() forces a write of all user-space buffered data for the given output or update stream via the stream's underlying write function. **For input streams, fflush() discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application**. The open status of the stream is unaffected.

Comment: It may be useful to note that this (Linux providing a definition for other-wise undefined behaviour) is an implementation-specific extension, and should be avoided by people who are interested in portable code.

Comment: @Emmet as you mentioned you required `fflush(stdout);` but it's working fine without that. can you give particular case where buffer is not full so `printf` is not able to print on screen.

Comment: @Emmet by the way thanks I forgot your explanation on `fflush(stdin)` is awesome, it's just clear explanation.

Answer (score 18):

`fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behaviour.

`fflush()` is defined only for output streams. You should not do it.

---

On Unix, Ctrl-Z sends a TSTP signal (SIGTSTP) which by default causes the process to suspend execution.