# How to combine two variables of different data types in C?

Tags: c

So basically I'm writing a piece of code for a tournament, and i have two varaibles the player number and the player name, how would i go about pairing/combining these two variables?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CONTESTANTS 16

int main(void)
{
    char array[CONTESTANTS][20];
    int n;



    for(n=0;n<CONTESTANTS;n++)
    {
       printf("Player %d: ", n+1); 
       scanf("%s", array[n]);
       fflush(stdin);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by pairing/combining? You can use struct to "pack"  different data types together.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` causes UB, doesn't it?

Comment: See [Structs in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm). It's better to avoid [fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901901/what-does-fflushstdin-do-in-c-programing/22901947#22901947).

Comment: You are already pairing them by storing the names in an array. The array index plus 1 is the player number. Likewise, the player number minus 1 is the array index for that player's name.

Answer (score 1):

use struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CONTESTANTS 16

typedef struct player {
    int number;
    char name[20];
} Player;

int main(void)
{
    Player array[CONTESTANTS];
    int n;

    for(n=0;n<CONTESTANTS;n++)
    {
       printf("Player %d: ", array[n].number = n+1); 
       scanf("%19s", array[n].name);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: how would I then print the 6th element of the player array, in a way that prints both the player number and name together? Thanks for help btw, is extremely useful

Comment: @kallumallen `printf("player no is %d\nname of player %s\n", array[5].number, array[5].name);`

Answer (score 0):

Use structs to store information about the contestants:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CONTESTANTS_LEN 16

#define NAME_LEN 20

struct Contestant {
    int contestant_id;
    char contestant_name[NAME_LEN];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Contestant contestants[CONTESTANTS_LEN];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<CONTESTANTS_LEN;i++) {
       printf("Player %d: ", i+1); 
             contestants[i].contestant_id = i+1;
       scanf("%s", &(contestants[i].contestant_name));
    }

  return 0;
}
```