# How to add a whitespace in between every string inputted into a text file

Tags: c, printf, text-files, fgets

Every time I input a string into my text file I want a space in between the strings inputted like this:

Input:

> Stack
>
> Overflow

Expected Output:

> Stack Overflow

Current output:

> StackOverflow

This is my function code:

```
void addDataToTextFile(FILE *fileptr)
{
    char text[100];
 
    fileptr = fopen("textfile.txt", "a");
    printf("\n\nPlease enter some text: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(text);
    fprintf(fileptr, text);
    fclose(fileptr);
    printf("\n\nText has been added");
    getch();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`gets` is deprecated, use `fgets` and replace the trailing newline with a white space:

```
void addDataToTextFile(FILE *fileptr)
{
    char text[100];
    char *ptr;

    fileptr = fopen("textfile.txt", "a");
    printf("\n\nPlease enter some text: ");
    fflush(stdin); /* You want fflush(stdout); */
    fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin);
    if ((ptr = strchr(text, '\n'))
        *ptr = ' ';
    fprintf(fileptr, text); /* Wrong, use fprintf(fileptr, "%s", text); */
    fclose(fileptr);
    printf("\n\nText has been added");
    getch();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with

1. always check the return value of `fopen()` before using the returned pointer.
2. `fflush(stdin);` produces undefined behaviour, is buggy and useless.<sup>##</sup>
3. `gets()` IS DANGEROUS. use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.
4. `fprintf(fileptr, text);` wrong usage.

Note: `fgets()` scans and stores the tralining `\n` (from <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press) from the input. After correcting above issues, to add a space after each input string, you can search and replace the traling `\n` with a  and then write the string to file. This is mentioned nicely in Mr. Alter Mann's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29138741/2173917) below / above.

---

`##`: As per `C11` standard, chapter `7.21.5.2`, paragraph 2,

> `int fflush(FILE *stream);`
>
> If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>   operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; ***otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.***

So, `stdin` which is not an outpust stream, will cause UB when used with `fflush()`.

Some good reads : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22901901/2173917) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18170410/2173917)

Comment: fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior. Meaning it is always a bug and potentially dangerous to use.

Comment: @Lundin yes sir, Was trying to say that only. Will update with your words. Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

FILE pointer was not declared
fprintf was missing the second argument

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        FILE *fileptr;
     char text[100];

        fileptr = fopen("textfile.txt", "a");
        printf("\n\nPlease enter some text: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(text);
        printf("INPUT = %s\n",text);
        fprintf(fileptr,"%s ", text);
        fclose(fileptr);
        printf("\n\nText has been added");
}
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion `FILE pointer was not declared`? I think it is there in function paramater, isn't it? Also, please don;t encourage using `gets()`, it's really bad, AFAIK.