# How fget works?

Tags: c, fgets

I am using **gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2**
I am writing a very simple script to take string as input and print the same with the some custom message. First user enters the T(no. of times to take string) and then takes input by **fgets**.
. I used [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Console/Usefgetstoreadstringfromstandardinput.htm)&[this](http://celsobarriga.com/2009/02/26/read-string-from-stdin-using-fgets/) as reference. 
 I am getting a very strange output ie fgets is adding some extra new lines and even loop is not working properly for T=2 it is asking input only once.
 Can anybody explain me what is wrong with snippet. Thanks in advance!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  int T;
  scanf("%d",&T);

 while(T--){
    char str[100]={""};
    int i;
    printf("Hello\n");
    fgets(str,80,stdin);
    i = strlen(str)-1;
    if(str[i]=='\n')
    str[i]='\0';
    printf("World\n");
    printf("%s\n",str);

  } 
   return 0;

}
```

Please see the image reference for T=2, even T=2 it is taking string only once and order of printing statement is also not as expected.
[image: when T=2 and]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your `scanf()` call

```
scanf("%d",&T);
```

does not consume the new line character `\n` accompanied by your input.

When you input `T`, your input is <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`scanf()` consumes the `2`, sees `\n` and stops consuming, leaving `\n` in the input buffer.

When the `fgets()` gets called, it sees the `\n` in the buffer and treats this as the input.

To solve this, you have a few choices (in decreasing order of my subjective preference):

1. Use `fgets()` to get the first input, then parse it using `strtol()` to get `T`.
2. Add an extra `fgets()` after the `scanf()`.
3. Add `getchar()` to consume one extra character. This works if you are certain that exactly one `\n` will be present after the input. So for example it won't work if you type <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. Alternatively, you may use `while(getchar() != '\n');` after the `scanf()` to consume everything up to a new line, but this may cause problems if an empty line is a valid input to your later `fgets()` calls.
4. If your implementation supports it, you may use `fpurge(stdin)` or `__fpurge(stdin)`.

And, very importantly, do **not** use `fflush(stdin)` *unless* your implementation clearly defines its behavior. Otherwise it is undefined behavior. You may refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22901901/3488231) for more details. Also, note that the `fpurge()` and `fflush()` methods may not work correctly if your input can be piped into the program.

Comment: understood, thnks ace!

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
scanf("%d",&T);
```

reads the input until the first non-numeral is found, which is `newline`. Then `fgets()` reads that newline for its first input.

I suggest using `fgets()` to read the number too.

```
fgets(str,80,stdin);
sscanf(str, "%d", &T);
```

Answer (score 1):

With your first call to scanf you allow the user to input an integer for the number of loops.  They do so, and use a carriage return to signal the end of input.  At this point scanf reads the integer, **but leaves the end-of-line (\n) in the stream.**.

So when you call fgets, fgets gets from the stream until it reaches the first newline -- in you code, on the first loop, this is the very first character it encounters.

If you discard the newline before calling fgets, you should get your desired results.  You can do this, for example by changing your first three lines to:

```
    int T;
    char newline;
    scanf("%d%c",&T, &newline);
```

Although there are probably stylistically superior ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a newline character in the input stream when you press "enter" after typing 2 for the first scanf. This is consumed by fgets() initially, hence it prints nothing (You replace the newline by `\0`).
2. In the next line, your input is read and echoed after `World` because you are printing it after it.