# loop through user input

Tags: c, fflush

I am trying to set up a loop where user can continue entering string. Not sure where i am going wrong (I am new to C programming)

this is the code i have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int repeat;
    char str[30];
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a string:");
        fgets(str, 30, stdin);
        printf("Do you want to continue\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf_s("%d", &repeat);
    } while (repeat==1);
}
```

This is the output i am getting:

```
Enter a string:hello
Do you want to continue
1
Enter a string:Do you want to continue
1
Enter a string:Do you want to continue
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First mistake `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior, probably harmless with the MSVC compiler but certainly wrong according to the standard, also `scanf_s("%d", &repeat);` is not standard either and has special syntax, I don't know exactly how special but I would suggest `scanf("%d", &repeat);` and try a different compiler like *gcc*. Also, `void main()` is wrong, and you must check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: @ace Even though the standard clearly states that `fflush()`'s behavior is only defined for output streams, Microsof has an implementation for it, and it's often seen in some tutorials online, primarily because of the wrong use of `scanf()` which is also very common.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30697465/3488231) and the accepted answer and see if you understand your problem.

Comment: If you feel comfortable with `fflush(stdin)`, then add another one after the `scanf()` call. The `\n` (from when you press <enter> after typing `1`) is being read by the next `fgets()`.

Comment: @ace I consider that this is a duplicate of that question, nice answer by the way.