# Scanf is skipped in while loop, causing infinite loop

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

The purpose of this code is so if the user enters an incorrectly formatted input, the program while ask the user to try again. For some reason though in my code, the scanf is constantly skipped after the first iteration, causing in infinite loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
double A1;
int n1, loopchck, i=0;
while (i==0) {
    printf("Enter a real number and inerger (A n): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    loopchck=scanf_s(" %lf %d", &A1, &n1);
    if (loopchck == 2) {
        i = 1;
    }
    else {
        i = 0;
    } 
} 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is UB, remove that.

Comment: in failure case, you need to cleanup stdin....

Comment: You're not calling the standard function `scanf` but instead `scanf_s`, which must be a custom function.  The issue is possibly related to what that function does.

Comment: Also related: you know that stdout is usually line buffered on terminals, right?  So there's a good chance that  your printf won't actually cause anything to appear on the screen.  You maybe wanted to `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: What do you mean, "cleanup stdin"?

Comment: What environment are we dealing with?

Comment: re the 1st comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22902085/2757035 "working by analogy, people often think that fflush(stdin) should discard any unused input, but if you think about it a little bit that doesn't make much sense."

Comment: `scanf()` is constantly skipped after the first iteration because the bad input is **still there**.  If input was bad for `scanf()`, why do you think calling the same code again will return different results.?  You need additional code to consume the offending input.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, lets think about what you want `fflush(stdin);` to do. `fflush` only operates on streams that have been written to; it causes any unwritten (cached) data to be fully written, and it makes no sense in the context of `stdin`.

This is a common mistake. When you tell `scanf` to read an integer (or a floating point, whatever) it'll stop reading when it no longer sees anything numeric. This means you'll probably have a leftover `'\n'` on the stream, at least. The user might have also entered other (erroneous) input that you want to discard.

The idea of *discarding user input* is horrible! You should think about accepting input in a different form (e.g. using `argv` in `int main(int argc, char **argv)`) to make their uncomfortable life a little more comfortable.

If you can't do that (or you don't want to), you can use one of the following pieces of code to discard up to (and including) the next `'\n'`:

```
void fdiscardline(FILE *f) {
    int c;
    do {
        c = fgetc(f);
    } while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
}

void fdiscardline(FILE *f) {
    fscanf(f, "%*[^\n]");
    fgetc(f);
}
```

You should use this *after* your input, not *before*. Also, you need to think about what `i` should be. Should it be zero when more input can be read (e.g. `while (i==0)`), or zero when input wasn't read correctly? You need to be consistent because that's your loops terminal condition. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double A1;
    int n1, loopchck, i=0;
    while (i==0) {
        printf("Enter a real number and inerger (A n): ");
        loopchck=scanf_s(" %lf %d", &A1, &n1);
        fdiscardline(stdin);
        if (loopchck == 2) {
            i = 0;
        }
        else {
            i = 1;
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```