# How is the working of fflush(stdin) changing the output in below code?

Tags: c, fflush

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int test_no ,count=1,i,n,j;
        scanf("%d",&test_no);
        fflush(stdin);
        int arr1[test_no];
        for(i=0;i<test_no;i++)
        {
                scanf("%d",&n);
                printf("\n");
                int arr[n];
                for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
                }
                for(j=1;j<=n-1;j++)
                {
                        if(arr[j-1]>arr[j])
                        {
                                count++;
                        }
                }
                if(n==1)
                {
                        arr1[i]=1;
                }
                else
                {
                        arr1[i]=count;
                }
                count=1;
        }
        for(i=0;i<test_no;i++)
        {
                printf("%d\n",arr1[i]) ;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This solution is to this [problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/speed-7/).

I am not getting the desired output for the third case , it's giving me output as 3 or 4 depending on whether I place `fflush(stdin)` before `scanf("%d",arr[i])` or after `scanf("%d",arr[i])` , please tell the problem with this code .

Comment: It looks quite funny, but please: format your code properly.

Comment: I'm reopening the question, as the marked dupe is very much relevant but __not__ a correct dupe. Other than the issue discussed in marked dupe, there __are__ other issues which needs to be addressed.

Comment: For Reference: The marked dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901901/what-does-fflushstdin-do-in-c-programing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In <del>no</del> *some magical* way.

First of all, `fflush(stdin);` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). ***Don't use that.***

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.5.2, *The `fflush` function* (*emphasis mine*)

> If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>   operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

That said,

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
```

looks pretty wrong to me, `arr[i]` is not guaranteed to be within bounds. It should rather be

```
scanf("%d",&arr[j]);
```

Comment: Yes , i just missed that point , thanks , but this undefined behaviour which you mentioned regarding fflush(stdin) , that I could not relate it properly , can you please explain this once again

Comment: @RADHAGOGIA: Is google unreachble from your site? You are expected to show at least a bit of effort on your own. If not for `fflush(stdin)`, the at least for "undefined behaviour"!

Comment: @RADHAGOGIA Which part you did not understand? All it says is, use `fflush` with a stream which is associated with output, like `stdout`. Don;t use it on input streams, like `stdin`.