# How to take string input simultaneously?

Tags: c, input, scanf, stdin, fgets

i am working on a database basic project 
consider a structure

```
struct student
{ 
int rollno;
char full_name[20];
char address[50];
char birthmark[50];
};
```

how to take this input

> rollno 6
>
> name john snow
>
> address winterfell of north
>
> birthmark swords wound all over

**What I have tried:**

i have tried

`scanf("%s",stringname)`,`scanf("%[^\n]s",stringname)`,`gets(stringname)`,
`fgets(buffer,size,stdin)` with `fflush(stdin)`.
there are always some error.
so far fgets work perfectly but I have read `ffush(stdin)` is a wrong practice .

so what should be the approach to take input of string (with spaces) simultaneously one after the another.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &studentVar.rollno);scanf("%*[^\n]");scanf("%*c");scanf("%19[^\n]%*c", studentVar.full_name);scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", studentVar.address);scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", studentVar.birthmark);`

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/I5QGgR)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you so much :)that helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach will be , reading a whole line from input by `fgets()` and then parse and validate before you populate the members of the structure. A flow chart can look like

```
fgets(into the buffer) and the return is not NULL
if (integer)
store into rollno;
else 
copy the input string into corresponding member variable.
```

And yes, `fflush(stdin)` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), [**don't use that**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325926/2173917).

---

(*Without the code with error and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that's all the help we can do*)

Comment: thanks but there are some  error when fgets is followed by scanf(),in that case what to do .                                                                        for example scanf("%s",var);fgets(par1,par2,par3); in this case fgets eat the new line left by scanf .should i flush that ?

Comment: @ekaf why don't you use `fgets()` all the time? (_Sorry, personally I'm not a fan of `scanf()` family_)

Comment: okay from now on words only fgets while dealing with string :) thanks for the help

Comment: If all learners started with `fgets()` and not "learned" with `scanf()`, think of all the fewer SO posts there would be.  @ekaf Also review http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359