# Application Crash when printing structure using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, mingw, structure

I wrote below code for reading/printing the structure using pointer. The application is printing the data, but later crashes. Seems to be some silly mistake somewhere. Unable to find the exact problem. I tried using pass by value in printStruct and returning structure in readStruct. There is no issue. When I use pointer not sure what is going wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

struct  student{
    char USN[10];
    char name[50];
    char gender;
    uint8_t age;
};


void printStruct (struct student*);
void readStruct(struct student*);


int main() {

    uint8_t numStudents;
    printf("Enter number of students\n");
    scanf("%d",&numStudents);
    struct  student firstSemStudent[numStudents];
    readStruct(firstSemStudent+0);
    printStruct(firstSemStudent+0);
    return 0;
}

void printStruct (struct  student *var1)
{
    printf("USN= %s\n",var1->USN);
    printf("Name = %s\n",var1->name);
    printf("Age = %d\n",var1->age);
    printf("Gender = %c\n",var1->gender);
}

void readStruct(struct student *temp)
{
    printf("\nEnter USN: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(temp->USN);
    printf("\nEnter Name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(temp->name);
    printf("\nEnter age\n");
    scanf("%d",&temp->age);
    printf("\nEnter the Gender as M/F");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&temp->gender);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `uint8_t *` is not a valid argument type for `%d` format specifier for `scanf()`. Using wrong type of argument invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After that, technically speaking, `fflush(stdin);` is again, undefined behaviour, [don't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325926/2173917).

Thirdly, [DO NOT use `gets()`, it is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917) due to easy possibility of buffer overrun. use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Fix all the issues (or rather, the warning messages your compiler is screaming to complain about), and run the code.

Comment: It worked after correcting the issues except fflush(). But my questions are: Why there is a gets() and fflush() if they do not work? How one has to know such issues? Scanf also gives trouble if we do not use fflush. I am really confused which is the best way to read from stdin? Also how can I read data for uint8_t? Assume that I do not want to go for int or short int.

Comment: What about format specifiers for unsigned char? I do not think it is there. How do we read 8 bit value without making use of %c? Also I read somewhere that uint8_t, uint16_t etc are standard way of declaring variables because they are independent of architecture. Any comments!

Comment: @Rajesh I have deleted earlier comment, which might be misleading. The point was, `scanf()` does not have a defined format specifier for `uint<N>_t` types, instead, you should be using `SCNuN` MACROs, as specified in the standard. You'll be needing `<inttypes.h>` for doing that.