# Why read from file and print to screen is not working? C

Tags: c

I am trying to open a file for reading and count the number of emptylines inside it and how many times the words(for, while, do/while) are there. For func4 it works but its not working in func2 and I dont know why? Is it something that count function cant get the str or what?

```
//func2
        void ShowResult() {
        char str[MAX], inputFileName[50];
        int fix, loopF=0, loopW=0, loopDW=0, empty=0;
        FILE *fp;

    system("cls"); // clears the screen
    printf("\n Type destination or the name of the result file.\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(inputFileName, 50, stdin);

    fix=strlen(inputFileName)-1; // checks if a newline exist and removes it
    if(inputFileName[fix]=='\n')
        inputFileName[fix]='\0';

        if((fp = fopen(inputFileName, "r"))==NULL) {
            printf(" Cannot open file.\n");
                return;
        }
    while(fgets(str, MAX, fp)) { // read line by line in file
            Count(str, &loopF, &loopW, &loopDW, &empty);
    }

    fclose(fp);
        printf("---------------------\n");
        printf(" Empty lines: %d \n\n", empty);
        printf(" Number of loops:\n");
        printf(" For: %d \n", loopF);
        printf(" While: %d \n", loopW);
        printf(" Do/While: %d \n", loopDW);
        printf("---------------------\n");
    return;
}

//Count func to calculate stuff

void Count(char *str, int *loopF, int *loopW, int *loopDW, int *empty) {
     int i, lines;
     char *p;
        if(choice=='4' || choice=='1' || choice=='3'){
            for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) {
                    // count loops
                    if(str[i]=='f' && str[i+1]=='o' && str[i+2]=='r') {
                            (*loopF)++;
                    }
                    if(str[i]=='w' && str[i+1]=='h' && str[i+2]=='i' && str[i+3]=='l' && str[i+4]=='e') {
                            (*loopW)++;
                    }
                    if(str[i]=='d' && str[i+1]=='o') {
                            (*loopDW)++;
                            if((*loopDW)>=1) (*loopW)--;
                    }
            }
                    // count empty lines
                p=str;
                lines=0;
                    while(*p!='\n'){
                        if(*p!=' ') {
                            lines=1;
                        }
                        p++;
                    }
                        if(!lines) {
                            (*empty)++;
                            lines=0;
                        }
        }
 }
//func4
void PrinttoScreen() {
    char str[MAX];
    int loopF=0, loopW=0, loopDW=0, empty=0;

    system("cls"); // clears the screen
    printf(" Type a program here. Ctrl+Z and enter to stop.\n");
    fflush(stdin);

        while((fgets(str, MAX, stdin))!=NULL){ // read line by line in stdin
            Count(str, &loopF, &loopW, &loopDW, &empty);
        }
                printf("---------------------\n");
                printf(" Empty lines: %d \n\n", empty);
                printf(" Number of loops:\n");
                printf(" For: %d \n", loopF);
                printf(" While: %d \n", loopW);
                printf(" Do/While: %d \n", loopDW);
                printf("---------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: Please use a debugger to narrow down/solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, don't do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38325926/2173917).

Comment: `choice` is not declared in the code that you provided. Please provide a [mcve] if you want help debugging your code.

Comment: What does the file look like? Would be helpful to show that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: `if(choice=='4' || choice=='1' || choice=='3')`
needs to change to: `if(choice=='4' || choice=='1' || choice=='3' || choice=='2')`