# char in buffer preventing input of integer

Tags: c, string, input, char, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n,m=5;
    char c;
    while(m>0)
    {
        m--;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n==42)
        break;
        printf("%d",n);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&c);
        puts(&c);       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Although I know that when a enter is pressed after entering a number at first `scanf`, it(enter) is taken as input by the second `scanf`, but my doubt is that, when I give `5ttttt` as input , the output is

```
5t
5t
5t
5t
5t
```

as there is no integer in input buffer, why it is not asking for input of integer|
Second question is, even if we follow the above behavior, then on giving input of `5t` and then pressing enter should take two characters as buffer ('t' and 'enter') but only t is taken in buffer and the output is

```
5t
```

but I expected the output

```
5t
5
```

as 'enter' would be taken in buffer and it will not ask for integer input in the second iteration of loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, don't do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325926/2173917)

Comment: Which platform are you working on?  If you're on Windows, you will get different behaviour than if you're on a Unix-like system.  See [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) for the details.  You should check the return value from `scanf()` each time you use it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i am working on Mac ,i also checked my input on ideone.com

Comment: If you're on a Mac, then `fflush(stdin)` is at best a no-op.  After reading the `5`, the `scanf("%c", &c);` reads a `t`; the next `scanf("%d", &n);` fails (but you ignored this) without changing `n`, and the `scanf("%c", &c);` reads a `t`.  This continues for 5 iterations, and then the loop terminates because of the count (`m`) dropping to 0.  You'd get better enlightenment if you entered `5tuvwx`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's exactly what i am asking , why the next `scanf("%d",&n);` fails and i tried the input 5tuvwx .

Comment: The `scanf("%d", &n)` fails because the next character is `t` (or `u`) and neither of those is a valid integer.  Did you see `5t / 5u / 5v / 5w / 5x` when you typed `5tuvwx`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , ya i saw `5t / 5u / 5v / 5w / 5x` , so if there are no valid integer , in the buffer , and we need input of integer , then we have to flush the input buffer , there is no other way.?

Comment: You can't `fflush()` the input buffer on Unix systems — you can on Windows (see the question I referenced earlier).  You could read until the newline: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;`.  You could read the line with `fgets()` and then scan it with `sscanf()` or `strtol()` or some other suitable function.  Either way works; what you're trying doesn't.  If you typed `5tuv`, then you'd get a chance to enter another integer afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, see this thread about [`fflush(stdin);` being undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325926/2173917), simply don't do it.

You can roll your own function go get this done. Something along the line of

```
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
```

should do the job nicely.

That said,

```
   puts(&c);
```

also  causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as `&c` does not point to a *string*. Variable `c` is of type `char`, it's not a `char` array with a mandatory null-termination required to be considered as *string*. so, due to memory overrun, you're essentially accessing out of bound memory which causes the UB.

Probably you want to use [`putchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/puts) instead.

Comment: @sauravghosh  ` while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }`   where to put this line in my code.

Comment: @ayush A) define `c` as `int` B) use instead of `fflush(stdin);`

Answer (score -1):

Avoid `fflush(stdin)`. Instead of `fflush(stdin)` you can use `getchar()`.
After giving an integer input by `scanf("%d", &n)` you'll press an Enter, right? That `\n` (new line character) will be taken by `getchar()` and you can safely take a character input by `scanf("%c", &c)`. Otherwise the `\n` will be taken by `c`.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but I suggest you illustrate how you'd use `getchar()` to clean up.  Note that the OP typed `5ttttt` as the first input line — you need to handle that correctly too.

Comment: @Jonathan Laffler Thank you.