# C Program ended even with getchar()

Tags: c, xcode, exit, getchar

I made this very very simple program on xcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   float fix;
   float var;
   float price;
   int res;

   printf("This BEP calculator uses this formula:");
   printf("\nFixed Costs ÷ (Price - Variable Costs per unit) = Breakeven Point in Units\n\n");

   printf("Input product costs: ");
   scanf("%f",&price);
   fflush(stdin);

   printf("Input fixed costs: ");
   scanf("%f",&fix);
   fflush(stdin);

   printf("Input variable costs per unit: ");
   scanf("%f",&var);
   fflush(stdin);

   res = fix / (price - var);
   printf("The break even point is roughly %d units\n",res);
   printf("Thank you from using this program\n");
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

But every time it gets to the result the program automatically closes, ignoring `getchar()`.

What's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, don't do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325926/2173917)

Comment: @agikarasugi  Use two calls of getchar:)

Comment: Regard the remaining `\n` in buffer.

Comment: Instead of `fflush(stdin)` do this: http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html.

Comment: There are already some thousand questions on SO regarding trailing new line in stdin.