# c - need an alternative for fflush

Tags: c, fflush

I am only allowed to use the standard c library so fpurge() is not an option form me.

```
int dim = 0;
int c = 0;

printf("Please enter a number");

while ( (( c = scanf("%d",&dim)) != 1 ) || (dim < 1) || (dim > UCHAR_MAX) )   
{
    if (c == EOF)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("[ERR] Enter a number\n");
    printf("Please enter a number");
}
```

The program should read in a number big than one and if there is any “wrong” input like letters it should go and deliver an error message. It works with fflush on my windows pc put the program should run on a Linux system.

How can I replace fflush that the programm still works? Because when I do not use it I come in an infinite loop.

The number which is entered determines how often a certain line of code is used in the rest of the program that is why I need an array.

Comment: Why can't you use `fflush`?  That's part of the standard lib.

Comment: [`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior, don't do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325926/2173917)

Comment: @Iguananaut yep, but this is a wrong usage.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't even read that far.

Comment: @Iguananaut Yes, but since it has an undefined behaviour it does not work with Linux

Comment: Don't use `scanf` but use `fgets` and parse the input yourself. Then you don't need to flush anything. `scanf` is not very useful for user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int dim = 0;

  for (;;)
  {
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    char buffer[30];
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    char *endpointer;
    dim = strtol(buffer, &endpointer, 10);

    if (*endpointer != '\n' || (dim < 1) || (dim > UCHAR_MAX))
    {
      printf("[ERR] Enter a number\n");
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  printf("The number you entered is: %d\n", dim);
}
```

After the call to `strtol`, `endptr` points to the first non digit char entered. If only digits have been entered, `endptr` will point to the `\n` that terminates the line, otherwise if e.g. `12x` has been entered, `endptr` will point to the `'x'`.

You may improve this by writing a `GetNumber` function so you can just write

```
dim = GetNumber();
```

or

```
dim = GetNumber("Please enter a number: ", "[ERR] Enter a number\n", 1, UCHAR_MAX);
```