# Assigning multidimensional array from a function call to a variable

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi guys I have a question

How do I pass a Multi-dimensional Array from a Function to the main function  and from there we want to pass it to another function.

```
float array2[][3] = get_sizes(numbers);
```

The compiler says that the string above is an error because getsizes is an invalid initaliser.
Can somebody tell us what we are doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance.

EDIT

```
int main() 

{  

float anzahl = get_number();

if(feof(stdin))
{
return 0;
}
int anzahl2 = anzahl;
float array2[][3] = get_sizes(anzahl);
if (feof(stdin)) 
{
  return 0;
}
triangulation(array2, anzahl2);  

return 0;
}

int get_number(void)
{
printf("Please enter the number of triangles to check: ");
int anzahl = 0;
char check = 0;
int ret = 0;
while(!(ret == 2 && check == '\n'))
{
ret = scanf("%d%c", &anzahl, &check);
if (feof(stdin))
{
  return 0;
}
if (check != '\n')
{
printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
printf("Please enter the number of triangles to check: ");
my_flush();  
}
if((check == '\n' && anzahl > UCHAR_MAX) || (check == '\n' && anzahl <= 0))
{
printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
printf("Please enter the number of triangles to check: ");
ret = 3;
}
}
return anzahl;

void my_flush(void) 
{
while(getchar() != '\n')
{
}
}

int vgl(const void *a, const void *b)
{
int aa, bb;
aa = *(int *)a;
bb = *(int *)b; 
return (aa - bb);   

float get_sizes(int anzahl)
{
float array [3] = {0,0,0};
float array2[100][3];
while(anzahl>0)
{
char check = 0;
int ret = 0;    
while(!(ret == 2 && check == '\n'))
{
  printf("Please enter the first number of the triplet: ");
  ret = scanf("%f%c",&array[0], &check);
  if (feof(stdin))
  {
    return 0;
  }
  if (check != '\n')
  {
    printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
    my_flush();  
   }
   if((check == '\n' && array[0] <= 0.0)|| (check == '\n' && array[0] >= 
   FLT_MAX))
   {
    printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
    ret = 3;
   }
   }
   check = 0;
   ret = 0;
   while(!(ret == 2 && check == '\n'))
   {
  printf("Please enter the second number of the triplet: ");
  ret = scanf("%f%c",&array[1], &check);
  if (feof(stdin))
  {
    return 0;
  }
  if (check != '\n')
  {
  printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
  my_flush();  
  }
  if((check == '\n' && array[0] <= 0.0)|| (check == '\n' && array[0] >= 
  FLT_MAX))
  {
  printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
  ret = 3;
  }
  }
  check = 0;
  ret = 0;
  while(!(ret == 2 && check == '\n'))
  {
  printf("Please enter the third number of the triplet: ");
  ret = scanf("%f%c",&array[2], &check);
  if (feof(stdin))
  {
    return 0;
  }
  if (check != '\n')
  {
  printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
  my_flush();  
  }
  if((check == '\n' && array[0] <= 0.0)|| (check == '\n' && array[0] >= 
  FLT_MAX))
  {
  printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
  ret = 3;
  }
  }
  qsort(array, 3, sizeof(array[3]), vgl);
  array2[anzahl][0]=array[0];
  array2[anzahl][1]=array[1];
  array2[anzahl][2]=array[2];
  anzahl--;
  } 
  return array2;

  float triangulation(float array2[100][3], int anzahl2)
  {
  int number = 1;
  while(anzahl2>0)
  {
  if(array2[anzahl2][0] == 1 && array2[anzahl2][1] == 1 && array2[anzahl2]
  [2] == 2)
  {
  printf("Tripelt %d (a=%f, b=%f, c=%f)is NO triangle.\n", number, 
  array2[anzahl2][0], array2[anzahl2][1], array2[anzahl2][2]);
  }
  else
  {
  printf("Tripelt %d (a=%f, b=%f, c=%f)is a triangle.\n", number, 
  array2[anzahl2][0], array2[anzahl2][1], array2[anzahl2][2]);
  if(array2[anzahl2][0] == array2[anzahl2][1] && array2[anzahl2][0] == 
  array2[anzahl2][2] && array2[anzahl2][1]== array2[anzahl2][2])
  {
  printf("It is an equilateral triangle.\n");
  printf("It is a isosceles triangle.\n");
  }
  else if(array2[anzahl2][0] == array2[anzahl2][1] || array2[anzahl2][0] == 
  array2[anzahl2][2] || array2[anzahl2][1]== array2[anzahl2][2])
  {
    printf("It is a isosceles triangle.\n");
  }
  else if(((array2[anzahl2][0])*(array2[anzahl2][0])) + ((array2[anzahl2]
  [1])*(array2[anzahl2][1])) == ((array2[anzahl2][2])*(array2[anzahl2][2])))
  {
    printf("It is a right triangle.\n");
  }
  } 
   anzahl2--;
   number++;
   }        
   }
```

This is the whole code i'ts long

and we aren't allowed to use global variables

Comment: what is `numbers`? and what is the signaturre of `get_sizes`?

Comment: don't assign 2d arrays...it's not possible in c

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show more code. Read this: [mcve].

Comment: I think you are confusing `float array2[][3]` in function signature with variable definition. it's not the same type.

Comment: @mch.; vector in c?

Comment: I have added more code to make things more clearer :) @MichaelWalz

Comment: Please learn how to indent your code.

Comment: Curious similarity with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073328/c-need-an-alternative-for-fflush/47073918). BTW do as I suggested there, no need for flushing, just don't use `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how in general it can be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N   3

float ( * get_sizes( size_t n ) )[N]
{
    float ( *a )[N] = malloc( n * sizeof( float[N] ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = i * N + j;
        }
    }

    return a;
}

void display( float( *a )[N], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%4.1f ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 4;
    float ( *a )[N] = get_sizes( 4 );

    display( a, n );

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 0.0  1.0  2.0 
 3.0  4.0  5.0 
 6.0  7.0  8.0 
 9.0 10.0 11.0
```

That is you need to allocate the array dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code indicates you how to send a bi-dimensional array to a function. The function `func1` retrieves the value in `float a` pointed by `int x` and `int y`. The same should be done also for more than two dimensions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float func1(float *,int x, int y,int mx, int my);

float func1(float * a,int x, int y,int mx, int my)
{
    if (x>=mx)
        return 0;

    if (y>=my)
        return 0;

    return a[x*my+y];
}

int main(void)
{
#define _MX 4
#define _MY 3
    int x, y;

    float a[_MY][_MX] = {
        {0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3},
        {1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3},
        {2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3}
    };

    for(x=0;x<_MX;x++) {
        for(y=0;y<_MY;y++){
            // With cast
            printf("x =%2d y =%2d => v = %f\n",x,y,func1((float *)a,x,y,_MX,_MY));
        }
    }

    puts("---------------------------------");

    for(x=0;x<_MX;x++) {
        for(y=0;y<_MY;y++){
            // Without cast
            printf("x =%2d y =%2d => v = %f\n",x,y,func1(a[0],x,y,_MX,_MY));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```