# Can't find the replacement of __fpurge(stdin);

Tags: c, text-files

I'm studying textfile topic in C and I have got a question: what can I use instead of `__fpurge(stdin);` but make this function work like `__fpurge(stdin);` and I am not allowed to include `<stdlib.h>` in this program. I have read this [c - need an alternative for fflush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073328/c-need-an-alternative-for-fflush) but as long as I'm not allowed to `#include <stdlib.h>` so I can't use `strtol`.

```
void generateBill() {
    FILE *fp, *fp1;
    struct Bill t;
    int id, found = 0, ch1, brel = 0;
    char billname[40];
    fp = fopen(fbill, "rb");
    printf("ID\tName\tPrice\n\n");
    while (1) {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp)) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%d\t", t.pid);
        printf("%s\t", t.pname);
        printf("%d\t\t\t\n", t.pprice);
        total = total + t.pprice;
    }
    printf("\n\n=================== Total Bill Amount %d\n\n", total);
    fclose(fp);
    if (total != 0) {
        //__fpurge(stdin);

        printf("\n\n\n Do you want to generate Final Bill[1 yes/any number to no]:");
        scanf("%d", &ch1);
        if (ch1 == 1) {
            brel = billFileNo();
            sprintf(billname, "%s%d", " ", brel);
            strcat(billname, "dat");

            fp = fopen(fbill, "rb");
            fp1 = fopen(billname, "wb");
            while (1) {
                fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
                if (feof(fp)) {
                    break;
                }
                fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
            }
            fclose(fp);
            fclose(fp1);
            fp = fopen(fbill, "wb");
            fclose(fp);
        }
        total = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose the input is redirected from file? You might as well `exit(0)`. If the objective is to prevent type-ahead causing unwanted input, you can issue a definite prompt like "Is it OK to format your drive: enter YES".

Comment: Purgeing input blocks the opportunity to redirect the input, right now I'm terribly bothered by such a crap. Design your program to not need this. If you urgently need console-only usage, consider using a standard library like "ncurses", and document it. But expect less impressed users...

Answer (score 0):

for a replacement for `__fpurge(stdin)`  suggest:

```
int ch;
while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}
```

which only requires `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: I must have been tired.  The second check of EOF should be a check for '\n'.   Answer corrected.

Comment: @thebusybee: [Control-D actually means “send input immediately.”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21365313/298225) It causes an end-of-file indication only if it is entered immediately after a Return/Enter or preceding Control-D.

Answer (score 0):

`__fpurge` is a non-standard function only available on some systems (glibc 2.1.95, IBM zOS...) that discards input read into the stream buffer not yet consumed by `getc()`.

As explained in the [linux manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/__fpurge), *Usually it is a mistake to want to discard input buffers.*

You read user input with `scanf()`, which stops scanning input when the requested conversion is completed, for example `%d` stops reading the characters typed by the user when it reads a character that cannot continue the number and leaves this character in the input stream. Since `stdin` is usually line buffered when attached to a terminal, you should just read and discard any remaining bytes in the line input by the user after you process the input.

Here is a simple function for this purpose:

```
int flush_input(FILE *fp) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}
```

You would call this function after processing user input and you should test the return value of `scanf()` to ensure the user input had the expected syntax.

Here is a modified version of you function:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

// return a non zero error code in case of failure
int generateBill(void) {
    FILE *fp, *fp1;
    struct Bill t;
    int id, found = 0, ch1, brel = 0;
    char billname[40];
    fp = fopen(fbill, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(sdterr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", fbill, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    printf("ID\tName\tPrice\n\n");
    while (fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp) == 1) {
        printf("%d\t", t.pid);
        printf("%s\t", t.pname);
        printf("%d\t\t\t\n", t.pprice);
        total = total + t.pprice;
    }
    printf("\n\n=================== Total Bill Amount %d\n\n", total);
    if (total != 0) {
        int res;

        printf("\n\n\n Do you want to generate Final Bill[1 yes/any number to no]:");
        while ((res = scanf("%d", &ch1)) == 0) {
            fprintf("Invalid input. Try again\n");
            flush_input(stdin);
        }
        flush_input(stdin);
        if (res == EOF) {
            fprintf("premature end of file on input\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return 2; 
        }
        if (ch1 == 1) {
            brel = billFileNo();
            snprintf(billname, sizeof billname, "bill-%d-dat", brel);

            rewind(fp);
            fp1 = fopen(billname, "wb");
            if (fp1 == NULL) {
                fprintf(sdterr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", billname, strerror(errno));
                fclose(fp);
                return 1;
            }
            while (fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp) == 1) {
                fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
            }
            fclose(fp1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```