# C - How to print calculated numbers that have 15 digits?

Tags: c

I tried to print the result of `99,999 * 99,999 * 99,999`, the result should have been `999,970,000,299,999` but what got printed instead was `18446744072244127711`. I tried to print `20000 * 20000 * 20000` and the result was pretty much the same. Can you guys tell me how to get the real result?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;

    printf("Insert number : ");
    scanf("%ld", &num);

    fflush(stdin);

    unsigned long long int total = num * num * num;
    printf("Result : %llu", total);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior, don't do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325926/2173917)

Comment: `scanf("%ld",&num)` is undefined behavior too, as `num` is `int`.

Comment: You seem to have overflowed the `int` value.

Comment: *Can you guys tell me how to get the real result* - use calculator? Or pen-and-paper?

Comment: scanf("%d",&num);

Comment: `num` has to be `long long`

Comment: @berendeanicolae Why?

Comment: because when you multiply int values, the result is calculated in a temporary int variable. then for the assignment a cast to long long occurs. but the result which does not fit in int was already computed so an overflow will happen

Comment: @berendeanicolae So casting will be sufficient. The `num` itself is likely not overflowing (well, it's an assumption one should check).

Comment: @berendeanicolae wow bro it work,thanks

Comment: @SouravGhosh bro can you tell me what is undefined behavior ? why cannot use fflush? i just know that one

Comment: @Kenny check the link.

Comment: @Kenny Undefined behavior = doing something dangerous that isn't covered by the C language. Most often, but not always, undefined behavior manifests itself as some sort of severe run-time bug.

Comment: See also [Why write 1,000,000,000 as 1000*1000*1000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t x = 99999;
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", x*x*x);
}
```

You may also be able to do this with `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` types, but these depend on your C implementation (the compiler you are using).

The arithmetic you attempted overflowed the supported range of the `int` type you were using. When programming, it is important to ensure that the calculations you do will not overflow the range of the types you use.

Additionally, you must be careful about types in C code:

- When using `scanf`, match the conversion specifier to the type. For example, when scanning a decimal numeral for an `int` object, you should use `%d`, not `%ld`. `%ld` is for `long int`.
- In `unsigned long long int total = num*num*num;`, the `unsigned long long int` affects the type of `total`. It does not affect the type used in the calculation `num*num*num`. In that expression, the type of `num` is used. To use `unsigned long long int` in the calculation, you would have to convert one or all of the operands to `unsigned long long int`, as by using a cast: `(unsigned long long int) num * num * num`.
- By assigning 99999 to a `uint64_t` object, which I named `x`, I ensured that `x*x*x` was calculated with `uint64_t` arithmetic. (`uint64_t` is a 64-bit unsigned integer.) Another way to do this would be with `UINT64_C(99999) * UINT64_C(99999) * UINT64_C(99999)`. `UINT64_C` is a macro defined in `stdint.h` that essentially means “treat this constant as having type `uint64_t` or wider (actually `uint_least64_t`).” This could also be done with `UINT64_C(99999) * 99999 * 99999` because C will automatically convert the narrower-type integer operands to the wider-type integer operand. It could also be done with `(uint64_t) 99999 * 99999 * 99999`.
- `PRIu64` is a macro that provides the right `printf` conversion specifier for `uint64_t`. It is defined in `inttypes.h`.

Comment: Pedantically, `UINT64_C` gives a literal of type `uint_least64_t` and not `uint64_t`.

Comment: Nice answer (as always). But I would make it clear that `(unsigned long long int) num * num * num` is only casting the first coefficient. The other two are implicitly converted.

Answer (score 3):

Bugs:

- `%ld` on an `int` invokes undefined behavior.
- `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behavior since stdin is an input stream.
- `num*num*num` is carried out on operands that have type `int`, so you get overflow if you attempt `99999 * 99999 * 99999` since this is a larger number than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (assuming 32 bit `int`).

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    printf("Insert number : ");
    scanf("%d",&num); getchar();
    long long int total = (long long)num*num*num;
    printf("Result : %llu",total);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```