# How do I accept my initial as input and print along with my name in C?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have been struggling to print my full name in the C language from past several days. After several tries this is what I came up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char yourname[20];
    int yourage;
    char initial;

    printf("Whats your name? ");
    scanf("%18[^\n]s", yourname);

    printf("And your initial is? ");
    scanf("%c", &initial);

    yourname[19] = '\0';
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("How old are you? ");
    scanf(" %d",&yourage);

    printf("Your name is %s %c and you are %i years old.\n", yourname, 
    initial, yourage);


    return(0);
}
```

When I compile and run the program, this is what I get. I am compiling with full warning turned on like so

```
make name

clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 - 
std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow    name.c  -lcrypt - 
-lm -o name
```

Please help..

```
Whats your name?        Alokananda
And your initial is? How old are you?   35
Your name is Alokananda 
and you are 35 years old.
```

Comment: [regarding `fflush(stdin);`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38325884/2173917)

Comment: `scanf("%c", &initial);` in this statement add a space before `%` --> 'scanf(" %c", &initial);`

Comment: The clue is in the output...why is your age on a separate line to your surname?

Comment: I replaced \t with a \n wherever required. I was suppose to be using that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: `scanf("%18[^\n]s", yourname);` --> `scanf("%19[^\n]", yourname);`  (19 and no s).    `yourname[19] = '\0';` not that useful here - better to check return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Curious, why a leading space in `scanf(" %d",&yourage);`, but not one in `scanf("%c", &initial);`?

Comment: That leading space in scanf(" %d",&yourage);unnecessary however it is required in scanf("%c", &initial);