# I really don't know what's wrong

Tags: c

This software may calulate the min e max temperature of some cities entered by keybord, but I've some problems with the scanf or the printf, because it shows the ram register value instood the effictive data. I don't know why my simple c script don't work any idea? (may the problems is on the scanf %g of the &rilevazioni[i].temp)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char nome [30] ;
    double temp;
}meteo;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    meteo rilevazioni[20];
    meteo min, max;
    double media = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int app = 0;
    int n;
    printf("quante citta' vuole inserire? (max 20 citta')\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n Inseriamo le rilevazioni");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n Inserisci il nome : ");
        scanf("%s", rilevazioni[i].nome);
        printf("\n Inserisci la temperatura : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%g", &rilevazioni[i].temp);
        if (i == 0)
            min = max = rilevazioni[i];
        else
            if (min.temp > rilevazioni[i].temp)
                min = rilevazioni[i];
            else if (max.temp < rilevazioni[i].temp)
                max = rilevazioni[i];
        media += rilevazioni[i].temp;
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    media = media / n;
    printf("\n La citta' con temperatura minima e': %s con una temperatura di: %g gradi ", min.nome, min.temp);
    printf("\n La citta' con temperatura massima e': %s con una temperatura di: %g gradi ", max.nome, max.temp);
    printf("\n Le citta' con temperatura maggiore rispetto alla media (%f) sono:", media);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (rilevazioni[i].temp > media)
        printf("\n La citta' : %s ha una temperatura di: %g gradi ", rilevazioni[i].nome, rilevazioni[i].temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: [`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, don't do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325926/2173917)

Comment: Please make sure you have a more descriptive title in your question so contributors can look for your post, and your questions become more "searchable" for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling your code will GCC and warnings on (`gcc temp.c -Wall`), it says:

```
test.c:25:17: warning: format ‘%g’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’
```

And indeed, `%g` expects a `float*`, if you want to read a double use `%lg`.

This is confusing, because there is no such distinction when calling `printf()`, but that is because when calling `printf` all arguments suffer default promotion, and all `float` values are promoted to `double`. But with `scanf()` you are passing pointers to values, so that promotion does not apply and you must be extra careful.

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you ,I compile my code with GCC

I found the index of min & max temperature (i_min & i_max) and I print the two cities which they have max_temperature & min_temperature like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct meteo{
    char nome [30] ;
    double temp;
}meteo;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    double media = 0;
    int i = 0, app = 0,n=0;
    do
    {
         printf("quante citta' vuole inserire?\n");
         scanf("%d",&n);
    }while(n<1||n>20);

    meteo rilevazioni[n];
    printf("\n Inseriamo le rilevazioni");
    double min, max;
    int i_min=0,i_max=0,k=0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n Inserisci il nome : ");
        scanf(" %s", rilevazioni[i].nome);
        printf("\n Inserisci la temperatura : ");
        scanf("%lf", &rilevazioni[i].temp);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            min = max = rilevazioni[0].temp;
        }
        else
        {k++;
            if (rilevazioni[k].temp<min)
            {
                i_min=k;
                min = rilevazioni[k].temp;
            }
            if (rilevazioni[k].temp > max)
            {
                i_max=k;
                max = rilevazioni[k].temp;
            }
        }
    }

printf("\n La citta' con temperatura minima e': %s con una temperatura  : %lf gradi ", rilevazioni[i_min].nome, rilevazioni[i_min].temp);
printf("\n La citta' con temperatura massima e': %s con una temperatura : %lf gradi ", rilevazioni[i_max].nome, rilevazioni[i_max].temp);

}
```