# fgets() goes newline when storing string but gets() no issue about newline

Tags: c

```
fseek(fPtr, 0, SEEK_END);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\t\t\t ENTERID : ");
    fgets(user.id, ID_SIZE, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("tENTER FIRST NAME: ");
    fgets(user.fname, MAX_FNAME_SIZE, stdin); //automatic added newline
    

    printf("ENTER LAST NAME: ");
    fgets(user.lname, MAX_LNAME_SIZE, stdin); //automatic added newline
```

I was using fgets() for reading the input of the string and store into the text file using the fwrite.
But why does fgets() automatically enter a newline for each input of string.

Comment: It is not automatic. You enter newline and `fgets()` saves it to the buffers.

Comment: Do not use `fflush(stdin);`, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: How to remove it automatically? @MikeCAT

Comment: The `fgets` stores the read newline character, while the `gets` discards the read newline character. It is by design.

Comment: [c - Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: @MikeCAT that mean we need to do another process to remove the newline \0? Like that link given using `strcspn`

Comment: @LucasJack - (From the comments under that link.)  _"This [method] handles the rare buffer than begins with `'\0'`, something that causes grief for the `buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';`"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"...but gets() no issue about newline"*
Note, that although your observation about `gets()` being preferable in this case over `fgets()` for handling newline, the unfavorable behaviors that come with [gets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) make it dangerous to use, with the result that *"it was officially removed by the 2011 standard."* ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694042/645128))  Even without the `\n` mitigations mentioned below, [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) is highly preferred over `gets()`.

*"fgets() goes newline when storing string..."*  and *"...why does fgets() automatically enter a newline for each input of string"*
`fgets()` does not *enter* the *newline* upon reading the line, rather if one exists, the *newline* is picked up as part of the line when `fgets()` called. For example in this case, when using `stdin` as the input method, the user clicks the `<return>` to finish inputting text. Upon hitting the `<return>` key, a `\n` is entered just like any other character, and becomes the last character entered.  When the line is read using `fgets()`, if the `\n` is seen before any of its other *stop reading* criteria, `fgets()` stops reading, and stores all characters, including `\n`, terminates line with `\0` and stores into the buffer.  (If `sizeof(buffer) - 1` or *EOF* is seen first, `fgets()` will never see the newline.)

To easily eliminate the `\n`, (or other typical unwanted line endings), use the following single line statements after each of your calls to [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm):

```
fgets(user.id, ID_SIZE, stdin);
user.id[strcspn(user.id, "\n")] = 0;
//fflush(stdin);//UB, should not be called 
...
fgets(user.fname, MAX_FNAME_SIZE, stdin);
user.fname[strcspn(user.fname, "\n")] = 0;
...
fgets(user.lname, MAX_LNAME_SIZE, stdin);
user.lname[strcspn(user.lname, "\n")] = 0;
...
```

This technique works for truncating any string by searching for the unwanted `char`, whether it be `"\n"`, `"\n\r"`, `"\r\n"`, etc.  When using more than one search character, eg `"\r\n"`, it searches until it reaches either the `\r` *or* the `\n` and terminates at that position.

*"This [method] handles the rare buffer than begins with `'\0'`, something that causes grief for the `buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';` [method]."*  (@Chux - comment section of link below.)

[Credit here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/645128)

Comment: Why this have added \r ?

Comment: @LucasJack - It does not need it, but does not hurt.  I will remove it for your code.  Some environments tack on the `\r` in addition to the `\n`.  See edit for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the man page,

> *`fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.** A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.*

So, after providing the input from the terminal, you press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key which adds a newline to the input buffer. That same newline is scanned and stored in the destination provided to `fgets()`.

If you want to remove the trailing newline, use the solution mentioned in the answer: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2173917)

That said, read:

- [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917)
- [How is the working of fflush(stdin) changing the output in below code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38325884/2173917)

Comment: `strcspn` so everytime i using fgets() i need to do this process to make sure no newline store?

Comment: @LucasJack - There are other methods, as seen in the link, but this one is elegant in that it is a simple and surprisingly versatile one line method.