# Issue with some simple logic and getting something to print C++ HouseWindowsLab

Tags: c, stdio

Please Help. This simple program is suppose to calculate users inputs for how many of each house they want. Multiply it by the windows each house adds. And apply 1% more windows to the total for spares. Why isn't the spare part working?

```
/*************************************
* PROGRAM: WindowCalculator
* AUTHOR: Matthew Nickles
* DATE: 9/6/2018
* NOTES: This is for educational purposes, the program calculates
* how many windows for each house plan a city builder would get.
**************************************/

/* PREPROCESSOR COMMANDS */
#include <stdio.h>


/* MAIN PROCESSING CONTROL */
int main()
{
/* VARIABLE DECLARATIONS */
int MontgomeryHouses; /*20 Windows per a house*/
int KetteringHouses; /*15 Windows per a house*/
int SaxonHouses; /*12 Windows per a house*/
int TotalWindows; /*Total calculation of all windows*/
int SpareWindows; /*How many spare windows if you wanted 1% of total*/ 

/* WINDOWS PER HOUSE ALGORITHM */
printf("\n How many Montgomery Houses do you wish to build? They have 20             windows. ");
scanf("\n%d", &MontgomeryHouses);
fflush(stdin);

printf("\n How many Kettering Houses do you wish to build? They have 15 windows. ");
scanf("\n%d", &KetteringHouses);
fflush(stdin);

printf("\n How many Saxon Houses do you wish to build? They have 12 windows. ");
scanf("\n%d", &SaxonHouses);
fflush(stdin);

/* CALCULATE TOTAL WINDOWS*/
TotalWindows = (MontgomeryHouses * 20) + (KetteringHouses * 15)
        + (SaxonHouses * 12);
SpareWindows = TotalWindows * 0.01;
/* DISPLAY OUTPUT*/
printf("The spare windows needed &d are windows.\n",SpareWindows);
fflush(stdin);  
printf("\nThe total amount of windows needed for all houses are %d windows.\n",TotalWindows);
fflush(stdin);



return 0;
}
/* END OF PROGRAM */
```

Comment: Take another look at the format specifier string for spare windows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Please do not tag a question with both [tag:c] and [tag:c++] — they are vastly different languages.  Your title mentions C++; your code is C.  Be cautious about [using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/) — it is not good practice on most platforms because it leads to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is totally fine. It is just a tiny syntax error.
In this line:

`printf("The spare windows needed &d are windows.\n",SpareWindows);`

`&d` should be replaced by `%d`.

I think you just overlooked it, because the other parts are perfect.

Comment: Tried running it,  here is what happened when I ran it.
---

`How many Montgomery Houses do you wish to build? 1


 How many Kettering Houses do you wish to build? 1


 How many Saxon Houses do you wish to build? 1


The total amount of windows for all houses are 47 windows.
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)`

It didn't even acknowledge one of the print statements lol.

Also im new so sorry about the formating >_>

Comment: No problems about the formatting buddy. But are you sure you didn't comment out the `printf` or something? Because this is what I got as the output:  `gcc version 4.6.3
               How many Montgomery Houses do you wish to build? They have 20             windows.  1
               How many Kettering Houses do you wish to build? They have 15 windows.  1
               How many Saxon Houses do you wish to build? They have 12 windows.  1
               The spare windows needed 0 are windows.
               The total amount of windows needed for all houses are 47 windows.'

Comment: and yes another thing, try working without the use of `fflush(stdin)`. It isn't a must for smaller programs. It also does cause problems at times.

Comment: I copied and pasted my source code, changed one thing and it worked again... it was that &d I have been working on that far too long.

Completely new to programing, slowly but surely I work my way. Its actually getting quite fun. Thanks you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. And could you tell me what caused that particular `printf` to not display even after making the change to the `&d`? Just curious to know.

Comment: @Rai: use of  `fflush(stdin)` must be avoided. It is an undefined behavior to use `fflush()` function for input stream`(stdin)`. This library function should only be used for output stream `(stdout)`

Comment: I actually can't. There were no error messages, or anything showing when I ran it. It drove me mad. Also it wasn't a comment and no syntax error (well has to be but none I found) as well.

Maybe it was the IDE? It might come clear to me on the morrow.

Comment: Yes @Destructor. So that is what caused his `printf` to not display then? I myself have witnessed some unusual behavior while using the `fflush`, didn't know this though. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Matthew, maybe it was the `fflush` as Destructor said.

Comment: @Rai: See my answer. I've provided links to gain more information about this issue. OP has used '\n' in `scanf()` which isn't necessary here and type of `SpareWindows` variable should be `float` instead of `int`

Comment: @MatthewNickles: Which compiler you are using ?

Comment: Yes @Destructor. But I feel he is right to use the integer type for the spare windows, because logically, one can't really think of buying a fraction(float type) of windows. Not from a coding POV, but just a practical thought. You do have a point though, regarding floats and percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that ints cannot have numbers after a point. E.g: `SpareWindows = 50.43`, but because you declared it as int, it get truncated to `50`. You might want to use `floats` instead, like:

```
/* VARIABLE DECLARATIONS */
int MontgomeryHouses; /*20 Windows per a house*/
int KetteringHouses; /*15 Windows per a house*/
int SaxonHouses; /*12 Windows per a house*/
int TotalWindows; /*Total calculation of all windows*/
float SpareWindows; /*How many spare windows if you wanted 1% of total*/
```

Since you total number of windows can always be just a "full" number, its perfectly fine to declare them as `ints`. But when moving to a percentage, like `SpareWindows`, you have to use `floats`. You might want to take a look [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/variables/create_float.php)

Comment: A very valid point syntactically Doctor. But practically, wouldn't be I guess. Not from a coding point of view, but you can't really have a fraction of windows, can you? Like, 0.53 spare windows for a total of 53 windows. So, logically, I feel he is better off using the Integers. Hope you don't take any offence, just sharing my opinion.

Comment: Exactly why I decided to use integer on this one.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>


/* MAIN PROCESSING CONTROL */
int main()
{
/* VARIABLE DECLARATIONS */
int MontgomeryHouses; /*20 Windows per a house*/
int KetteringHouses; /*15 Windows per a house*/
int SaxonHouses; /*12 Windows per a house*/
int TotalWindows; /*Total calculation of all windows*/
float SpareWindows; /*How many spare windows if you wanted 1% of total*/ 

/* WINDOWS PER HOUSE ALGORITHM */
printf("\n How many Montgomery Houses do you wish to build? They have 20             windows. ");
scanf("\n%d", &MontgomeryHouses);
fflush(stdin);

printf("\n How many Kettering Houses do you wish to build? They have 15 windows. ");
scanf("\n%d", &KetteringHouses);
fflush(stdin);

printf("\n How many Saxon Houses do you wish to build? They have 12 windows. ");
scanf("\n%d", &SaxonHouses);
fflush(stdin);

/* CALCULATE TOTAL WINDOWS*/
TotalWindows = (MontgomeryHouses * 20) + (KetteringHouses * 15)
        + (SaxonHouses * 12);
SpareWindows = (float)TotalWindows * 0.01; //Used Explicit type conversion to float
/* DISPLAY OUTPUT*/
printf("The spare windows needed %f are windows.\n",SpareWindows);
fflush(stdin);  
printf("\nThe total amount of windows needed for all houses are %d windows.\n",TotalWindows);
fflush(stdin);



return 0;
}
/* END OF PROGRAM */
```

Here actually the problem is when you try to multiply an integer by a decimal, output get converted to integer, so we must explicitly specify that value should be a float.
Hope that worked.

Comment: I think that would be very helpful, however I can't even get `prinf("The total amount of windows...` show up when I run it.

Comment: Yes the problem was with your `&d` on `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your program.

Let me start to point out them one by one.

Consider: `scanf("\n%d", &MontgomeryHouses);`

Why you've used `'\n'` in the `scanf()` ? There is no need to use `'\n'` here when you are taking an input.

I see that you've used `fflush(stdin);` 5 times in your program. Stop using `fflush(stdin)` in your C programs. `fflush()` function should only be used for output stream. Read [*Standard streams*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) to know more information about this. Use of `fflush(stdin)` is an [*Undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in both C & C++. Read the answers of these questions [What does fflush(stdin) do in C programing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901901/what-does-fflushstdin-do-in-c-programing) & [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the more information.

Another issue is that you've written `SpareWindows = TotalWindows * 0.01;`. You want to use floating point value in `SpareWindows` variable but the data type of this variable is defined to be of type `int`. It should be defined as `float SpareWindows;` So you'll have to use `'%f'` format specifier to print the value of this variable.

Comment: Yeah I removed all the fflush and cleaned it tf up. If its a floating point window wouldn't you have a weird percentage of a window instead of just one?

Comment: @MatthewNickles: How weird ?