# C Program not printing the string in a structure

Tags: c, string, for-loop, structure

I made a program to take multiple inputs as string, store and print them.
Somehow the "Account Number" that's stored in `a[i].acn` is not printing. I've tried debugging and the problem seems to be in the loop that adds spaces to `a[i].name` .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Bank
{
    char name[10],acn[8];
    float bal;
}a[100];
int n,i,flag;
void add()
{
//function to add Rs. 100 to accounts that have balance over 1000
//and print the details.
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(a[i].bal>=1000)
            a[i].bal+=100;
    printf("\nS.No.\tName\t\tAcc. No.\tBalance(in Rs.)");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("\n[%d]\t%s\t%s\t%.2f",i+1,a[i].name,a[i].acn,a[i].bal);
}
void main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of customers: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the details of %d customers:\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nCustomer-%d",i+1);
        printf("\nFirst Name: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(a[i].name);
        printf("Account Number: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(a[i].acn);
        printf("Account Balance: ");
        scanf("%f",&a[i].bal);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)//The problem seems to be in this loop
        while(strlen(a[i].name)<10)
            strcat(a[i].name," ");
    add();
}
```

Input:

```
Enter the number of customers: 2
Enter the details of 2 customers:

Customer-1
First Name: Aarav
Account Number: ASDF1234
Account Balance: 1200

Customer-2
First Name: Asd
Account Number: abcd1122
Account Balance: 999.9
```

Output:

```
S.No.   Name            Acc. No.        Balance(in Rs.)
[1]     Aarav                   1300.00
[2]     Asd                     999.90
```

Comment: What input was used?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica , my bad. I'll edit and add the input as well.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` Flushing an input stream is causing undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`scanf()` then `gets()` is bad**

`scanf("%d",&n);` reads the integer, yet leaves the following `'\n'` in `stdin` that `gets()` reads as an empty *string* `""`.

I recommend to use `fgets()` to read all the line into a sizable buffer and then parse using `sscanf()`, `strtol()` etc.

---

**Code overfills buffer**

`a[i].nam` only has enough room for 9 characters and then the *null character*.  Appending a space until it has a length more the 9 overfills `.name[10]`.

```
struct Bank {
  char name[10],acn[8];
  float bal;
} a[100];

while(strlen(a[i].name)<10)
   strcat(a[i].name," ");
```

Use `while(strlen(a[i].name)<9)` to pad with spaces, but not too many.

---

Money needs special [considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214586/2410359).  For now, consider a `long` of lowest denominational (cents).  Read in a `double` and then `long balance = lround(input*100.0);`

Other weaknesses exist.

Comment: Yes, `gets` **after** `scanf` is bad but.... `gets` is **always** bad - even without a `scanf` just before.

Comment: Thanks @chux-ReinstateMonica for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to correct in your program.

1. Use `fgets` instead of `gets` because in `gets` there is no boundary check and there is a danger of reading beyond the allocated size.
2. When using `fgets` , `scanf` and even `gets` they all read the left over `\n` characters from the standard buffer , so using `fgets` we can avoid it if we properly use it.(`scanf`  also avoids space characters but it cannot be used to read multiword strings)
3. remove `fflush(stdin)`, its not required you can see reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901901/what-does-fflushstdin-do-in-c-programing)
4. And last, but certainly not least use `int main()` instead of `void main()`

Comment: Point 2 is incorrect in several ways, e.g. that `scanf` can't read multi-word strings - it can.

Comment: @4386427, please mention those,  will add to the answer, end goal is to help.

Comment: "scanf ...  but it cannot be used to read multiword strings" --> `scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]" "%*[^\n]%*1[\n]" "%*[^\n]%*1[\n]" );` will nicely read in 3 non-empty lines of input.  Still,  using `fgets()` is a _good_ and preferable idea.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, this is good to know, then i should change my answer to _it cannot read in a straight forward way (just using `%s`) unless we use few list of escape sequence characters._

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answer and helpful comments!

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
struct Bank
{
    char name[10],acn[8];
    float bal;
}a[100];
```

since C strings must end with a NUL character (aka `'\0'`) the `name` can be at maximum 9 chars long.

But here

```
    while(strlen(a[i].name)<10)
        strcat(a[i].name," ");
```

you keep adding spaces until it's 10 characters long. In other word - you write outside the array.

Change `name` to be `name[11]`

Besides that `gets` and `fflush(stdin)` should be avoided.