# There is a logical error, what should i do?

Tags: c, function, stack

There's a minor data structures using c project I'm doing in college.
In that I'm having an logical error,
It's a quiz, and has two modules (subjects) in it.
I'm taking this two cycles, 1.first attemp, 2.retest.

1. (A) for 1st subject, the score is calculated correctly.
   (B) for 2nd subject, the score isn't calculated properly.
2. (A) for 1st subject, the score is calculated correctly.
   (B) for 2nd subject also, the score is calculated correctly.

It calculates properly on retest but not on first attempt.
What should i do ?!

Comment: code(.c file):->https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DfbCLe6txMFDYuorCvXZLfqT60ESBbMc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Code must be in the question as text in the form of a [mre]

Comment: it's a 328 line code

Comment: Hence "minimal"

Comment: What to do? Step through the code execution with a debugger.

Comment: when i minimized the code, it worked properly.it's just not working on the larger version.

Comment: Maximize the compiler warnings too and attend to every one.

Comment: it is working for half the no. of question's present in the first program, is there any stuff like data not loading properly in the first attempt because in the large program it works well on the retest of the entire program.

Comment: If you minimize the code and it's working, the error is most probably in the difference. Add it with as small as possible steps and watch when the error pops up. There you are!

Comment: actually it is only deleting some printf's and stack[5-9]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22901901/1216776

Comment: Eliminate global variables.